# how to use collection type in PLSQL, while receiving multiple value from front end java page?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Actually my requirement is,am having 3 tables so i need to create type for each table or consolidate type to all table. but in java developer have to send the multiple parameter to my Procedure, so how to get the multiple values in single type and insert it into table??

**Object type**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "POL_QUAT_TYPE" 
  IS OBJECT (V_POLICY_NO VARCHAR2 (30),
             V_FOREIGN_POLICY VARCHAR2 (1));
```

**tabletype**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE POL_QUAT_table IS TABLE OF POL_QUAT_TYPE
```

**Sample procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1 (A POL_QUAT_TYPE) IS
  B VARCHAR2(100);
  C VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  B:=A(1);
  C:=A(1);

  INSERT INTO TEST ( PART, B )
  VALUES (B,C);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

**Call this procedure**

```
begin
  test1('a','b');
end;
```

I want to know how get the value (a,b) though procedure from collection type.

Comment: HOW TO READ COLLECTION TYPE VALUES IN PROCEDURE           
 BEGIN
 pr_perform_task('1','2','3','4');
END;                                                                                                        
                                                                                            
  PROCEDURE pp (inp p_type) IS
    BEGIN   (how to read 1,2,3,4) values using this type (ptype) end;

Comment: So, if I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly, you have a collection that you want to insert all the elements of the collection into a table? Currently, you're thinking that you would loop through the array to get the values from the collection so you can call the test1 procedure - is that correct?

Comment: yah... and im trying to pass multiple data into single collection parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can insert the contents of an array of objects into the table like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "POL_QUAT_TYPE" 
  IS OBJECT (V_POLICY_NO VARCHAR2 (30),
             V_FOREIGN_POLICY VARCHAR2 (1));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE POL_QUAT_table IS TABLE OF POL_QUAT_TYPE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1 (p_a in POL_QUAT_table)
as
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST (PART, B)
  select t.v_policy_no,
         t.v_foreign_policy
  from   table(p_a) t;

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I've created [a test case](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/fh3ymv9wrpvkove1wvnnnzvdo) to demonstrate that it works over on Oracle LiveSQL.

This means you can insert all the content of the array in one go without having to loop through the array and insert one record at a time, so it should be much more performant.

Comment: I'm glad. Hopefully, next time you ask a question on here, you'll know how to write it with enough information so we can help you faster *{:-) (It's frustrating wanting to help someone, but being unable to due to lack of information! We **want** to help!)

Comment: how can i call this procedure..?  Boneist

Comment: I provided a link to the test case... that should show you how to call it.